# SQL Server 2008 Full text search on a table with a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, primary-key

I am trying to put full text search working on SQL Server 2008, however the table i am trying to index is a table with a composite primary key, something like this:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'My_Catalog', 'create'
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'Message', 'create', 'My_Catalog', 'PK__MESSAGES__C87C0C9C0EC32C7A' // PK__MESSAGES__C87C0C9C1EC32C6A is a composite key
```

and I get the following error:

> "'PK__MESSAGES__C87C0C9C1EC32C6A' is not a valid index to enforce a
>   full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique,
>   non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined
>   on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, does
>   not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another
>   index for the full-text key."

This means that I can't use the full text search in tables with composite primary keys? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty clear, no?

> "`PK_MESSAGES_C87C0C9C1EC32C6A` is not
>   a valid index to enforce a full-text
>   search key. A full-text search key
>   must be a **unique, non-nullable,
>   single-column index** which is not
>   offline, is not defined on a
>   non-deterministic or imprecise
>   nonpersisted computed column, does not
>   have a filter, and has maximum size of
>   900 bytes. Choose another index for
>   the full-text key."

If your index is not unique, not non-nullable, and not single-column, it cannot be used for fulltext indexing.

> This means that i can't use the full
>   text search in tables with composite
>   primary keys? Or am i doing something
>   wrong?

No, as the error says - this kind of index will not work. Period. No way around it.

As Remus pointed out - it doesn't ever say it has to be the primary key index! If you have some other non-nullable and unique field on the table, you can use a unique index on that field for your purposes. You could even just simply add a `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` field to your table and put a `UNIQUE INDEX` on that single field and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thats what i was expecting, i could just be mistaken, because a composite primary key is still a unique constraint (but not single-column, thats the problem).
Thank you very much, i just created the unique field, and worked =)

Answer (score 5):

> A full-text search key must be a
>   unique, non-nullable, single-column
>   index which is not offline, is not
>   defined on a non-deterministic or
>   imprecise nonpersisted computed
>   column, does not have a filter, and
>   has maximum size of 900 bytes.

Note that it doesn't have to be the primary key (ie. the PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table). Any unique index on a non-nullable single column will work. If you don't have such a column, add an identity column to the table and add an index to it, then use this index for the full text catalog.